# BINARY BYTE TO ASCII COVERVERTION?

Tags: vim, binary, ascii

I have a file consist of both ascii and binary data . Using vim i view that in binary format , its look like

```
0000000: 00100100 01010101 00101100 00100000 01001110 00110100  $U, N4
0000006: 00110110 00110100 00110101 01001011 00101010 00110101  645K*5
000000c: 01000110 00001101 00001010 00100100 01000001 00101100  F..$A,
```

Here i found that ASCII also show the binary values, but that binary data shows as "." In above example "f..$a" . What are that dots represents? I also tried online binary to ASCII converter for that ".(dot)" bytes 0001101 and 0001101 , but they shows nothing . What they belongs to represent?

Comment: What's with the caps?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking , although i tried my best to format and rephrase but i am clueless,can you just rephrase your statement please.

Comment: glad to you kabir , i have file it contains some characters in binary representation . so using vim feature i view it as binary . so i see stuff like above i pasted . in that the binary data,s are represented as (dots) please refer above "F..$A" . and they also have binary value like F ,$ A . but i cant even convert them to text using binary to ascii converter , what are they stand for ??

Comment: @Kabir: Why do you place `@` notification syntax in code spans? That stops the intended person from being notified.

Answer (score 4):

Those two binary values `00001101 00001010` are shown as `..` in the ASCII dump on the right. If you translate them to hexadecimal, you'll see that these are **0x0d 0x0a**, also known as *Carriage Return* (CR) and *Line Feed* (LF), as any ASCII table will tell you. The text file you're viewing has Windows-style line endings!

These are whitespace characters, and if included literally **would mess up the ASCII table**. That's why they (as well as the unprintable control characters below 32, and any binary values above 127, which aren't defined by ASCII and would need another character set to be interpreted correctly) are represented by `.`

In general, the binary / hex information in a dump is the authoritative one, the ASCII representation to the right is only to aid human comprehension.

Comment: IS IT EVERY BINARY BYTE , EVEN I TRY LITERALLY SHOULD HAVE A ASCII REPRESENTATION ? FOR EXAMPLE (10101010)

Answer (score 0):

The dots represent characters that are either whitespace characters, or characters that don't have an equivalent encoding in the utility you're using. 0001101 is 13 in decimal, which in ASCII is a newline character.

Comment: BUT I HAVE ONLY PASTED SOME STUFF FROM MY BINARY FILE . BUT SO MANY BYTES LIKE   00001010 AND 01000101 ETC ALSO SHOWING (DOT)

Comment: Like I said, it's a whitespace character (a space, a tab, or newline) or a character that does not have a symbol in the font your program's using, and it maps them to dots to make them visible.

Comment: @Vignesh: why are you typing with all caps? It's rather annoying.

Comment: sorry friend , from now i will text ,like it

Comment: If it's binary data, it really depends on how your data management works.

Comment: am new here , why people putting negative vote fro my question ?